# How to correctly perform SSR on e-commerce website?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, e-commerce, server-side-rendering

I'm gonna build a website for pizza shop using MERN stack. From features I want to add possibility to add categories and items to that categories from Admin panel (so client could customize his menu on the website). So the question is: is it even possible to SSR the home page where all the dynamic content will show up (new categories and menu items) or not? And do I even need that? (I just want that for SEO)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is certainly possible. Look at [Next.js](https://nextjs.org/) project which can help you with SSR and even static website generation.